# Crankshaft pulley remover

Tags: toyota

Can anyone please tell me what size crankshaft pulley remover I need, There are three sizes,  3: 6" 8" I suspect the 8" pulley would be the correct side and will screw into the bolt holes and then just keep pulling until the pulley comes off. I dont think its necessary to change the water pump as with todays coolants there is no corrosion in the radiator or in the thermostat housing.

Thans in advance.

Comment: Specific make and model and engine size would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. I'll measure the distance between the two holes in the pulley and know which one to use.I am sure I mentioned that the vehicle is a 1991 Toyota V6 4runner 3.0 litre

Answer (score 1):

The size of pulley remover needed is the one that fits the best given the spacing of the holes and how much force will need to be applied.

So, if you use the 6" and the pulley does not come free, then don't wind on it until it bends or breaks, change it for the larger one and consider if the technique can be changed.